# En este código al entrar se ejecuta el código

Tags: php, php5

En este código al entrar se ejecuta el código y aparecen los errores de:
1. "Debes poner un usuario o un e-mail."
2. "Debes poner una contraseña."
¿Alguna sugerencia para ayudarme?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

```html
<?php 
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('Location: personajes'); 
    exit();
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Iniciar sesión en United States Roleplay</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
   <div id="formContent">
     <h2 class="active"> Ingresar </h2>
     <a href="registrarme/index.php">
       <h2 class="inactive underlineHover"> Registrarme </h2>
     </a>
     <div class="fadeIn first">
       <img src="images/logo.jpg" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
    </div>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
      <p id="error" style="color:#B22222"></p>
      <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="usuarioingresado" placeholder="Escribe tu usuario o e-mail">
      <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="contraingresada" placeholder="Escribe tu contraseña">
      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Entrar">
   </form>
   <div id="formFooter">
     <a class="underlineHover" href="recuperar">¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
include 'scripts/conexion.php';
$arrDatos=array();
$arrDatos['usr']  = (!empty($_POST['usuarioingresado']) ) ? array ('data'=>$_POST['usuarioingresado']) : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Debes poner un usuario o un e-mail.');
$arrDatos['pwd']  = (!empty($_POST['contraingresada']) )  ? array ('data'=>$_POST['contraingresada'])  : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Debes poner una contraseña.');
if(array_column($arrDatos, 'msg')) {
    $msgs=implode("<br />",array_column($arrDatos, 'msg'));
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '".$msgs."'</script>";
} else {
  $ce = strtoupper( hash('whirlpool', $arrDatos['pwd']['data']) );
  $lp = array(" ", "-","DROP", "TABLE", "SELECT", "INSERT", "VALUES", "FROM", "INTO", "CREATE", "SET", "SQL", "PDO", "$", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "'", "=", ";");
  $u=$arrDatos['usr']['data'];
  $ul = str_replace($lp, "", $u);
  $c=$arrDatos['pwd']['data'];
  $bR = "SELECT * FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = '$ul' or Email = '$el' and Contra = '$ce'";
  $r  = $con->query($bR);
  $c1 = mysqli_num_rows( $r );
  if( $c1 === 1 ){
    session_start();$_SESSION['usuario'] = $ul; header("Location: personajes");
  }else{
      echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Los datos de inicio de sesión son incorrectos.'</script>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar una captura de pantalla del error?

Comment: @nashvent https://imgur.com/a/fXLt83p .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al iniciar la pagina esta validando la existencia del usuario y contraseña y esa validación solo se debe de hacer cuando se esta en el metodo POST. Agregando `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` a la condición que agrega los mensajes de error evitas que se muestren antes de enviar los datos.

```html
 
$arrDatos['usr']  = (!empty($_POST['usuarioingresado']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) ? array ('data'=>$_POST['usuarioingresado']) : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Debes poner un usuario o un e-mail.');
$arrDatos['pwd']  = (!empty($_POST['contraingresada']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  ? array ('data'=>$_POST['contraingresada'])  : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Debes poner una contraseña.');
```